# jQuery Autocomplete Not Working With Array Datasource

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have created a jQuery autocomplete that works of an array generated by a PHP script:

```
var tags = [{"id":"77","label":"110826"},
            {"id":"76","label":"110667"},
            {"id":"74","label":"110808"}];
```

However the autocomplete box will not work - i am typing in values that are in the array but nothing is happening and I cannot figure out why.

Please see my fiddle here; http://jsfiddle.net/j4yB3/

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: [Works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/j4yB3/3/) - you didn't include jQuery or jQuery UI in the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You hadn't closed your `<label>` tag (not that it **really** matters), but your Fiddle didn't have the jQueryUI and jQuery references.

Try [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/j4yB3/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the fiddle code for the solution. Make sure you have added the jquery js and jquery ui js

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var projects = [
      {
        value: "jquery",
        label: "jQuery",
        desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
        icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
      },
      {
        value: "jquery-ui",
        label: "jQuery UI",
        desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
        icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
      },
      {
        value: "sizzlejs",
        label: "Sizzle JS",
        desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
        icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
      }
    ];

    $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: projects,
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
        $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
        $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
        $( "#project-icon" ).attr( "src", "images/" + ui.item.icon );

        return false;
      }
    })
    .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
  });
  </script>
```